# Sublime Text 3 - "Install Package" Package Control Missing

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm following [the instructions found here](https://packagecontrol.io/installation), the "Manual" part (since I'm having a proxy on my network).

I downloaded `Package Control.zip` and extracted its contents to the manually created `C:\Users\mblument\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Package Control.sublime-package` directory.

After that, I restarted sublime and pressed `Ctrl+Shift+p`.

Then I started to type "Control Package" but it offered nothing (unlike [here](https://blog.cs.wmich.edu/sublime-text-putty-and-you/)). I was expecting "Package Control: Install Package" to be suggested. What's wrong?